# Is there a way to add additional CSS styles to the styles css file dynamically?

Tags: css

I would like to add additional styles to the styles.css file before it is sent to the client. Is this possible?

Currently styles.css contains :

```
/*
Theme Name: My Theme
Theme URI: https://example.com/themes/vanilla/
...
*/

...

html {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

// MY ADDITIONAL CSS HERE
```

I would like to add additional CSS dynamically to the end of that file. Is that possible?

For example, in my index.php:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : 

   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   // normal post stuff


    moreCSS = $myPost->moreCSS;
    addMoreCSSToStyles_css(moreCSS);

    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: This wouldn't be the most efficient method, you should either output it dynamically at runtime or enqueue a new stylesheet written by your code

Comment: How would I enqueue it?

Answer (score 2):

You can [enqueue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) a different stylesheet only for `index.php` using [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

The following code should be added in `functions.php`

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() 
{
 if ( is_home() ) 
 {      
      wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name',  get_template_directory_uri() .   "/path_to_file/yourStylesheet.css' ); 
 }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case I don't have a CSS file to link to. What I want to do is add more CSS to the existing styles.css. From your link on *enqueue* I found this function, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style. I think that will do what I want but I'm not sure where to put it.

Comment: You can add it into the functions.php and call it with add_action '<?php
function my_styles_method() {
 wp_enqueue_style(
  'custom-style',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_script.css'
 );
        $color = get_theme_mod( 'my-custom-color' ); //E.g. #FF0000
        $custom_css = "
                .mycolor{
                        background: {$color};
                }";
        wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );'
?>